# Wifi suddenly stopped working in Ubuntu 22.10. Question mark for wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi, 22.10

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10 with an Intel Wifi AX210 chip. It's a fresh install and I've been using Wifi all day until suddenly it stopped working and I see a question mark where the Wifi symbol should be. The internet definitely works, something is up with my machine.

Here's outputs from various commands in solutions I've tried

```
hakuna@hakuna-desktop:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
hakuna@hakuna-desktop:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp5s0    no wireless extensions.
wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"partyhouse2.4ghz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: 88:81:B9:AD:8A:6C   
          Bit Rate=245 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:5   Missed beacon:0
docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

```
hakuna@hakuna-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 0a:e0:af:b5:00:2a
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-31-generic firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fbd00000-fbd00fff memory:f0300000-f0303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 70:1a:b8:96:a6:86
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-31-generic firmware=71.058653f6.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-71.uc ip=192.168.3.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:fbc00000-fbc03fff
```

```
hakuna@hakuna-desktop:~$ lsmod | grep iwlw
iwlwifi               503808  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211             1040384  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

```
hakuna@hakuna-desktop:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[    4.006151] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.021494] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.052106] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.052129] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[    4.052763] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.216699] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    4.383826] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded PNVM version 881c99e1
[    4.398813] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    4.468202] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: base HW address: 70:1a:b8:96:a6:86
[    4.486507] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
```

```
[    4.112873] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'd0i3_disable' ignored
[    4.112881] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'lar_disable' ignored
[    4.171228] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.174690] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.181574] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.181607] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[    4.182172] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.339703] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    4.507014] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded PNVM version 881c99e1
[    4.522015] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    4.591625] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: base HW address: 70:1a:b8:96:a6:86
```

Looks like the problem might be here:

```
 Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.052106] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
```

Looking around I saw suggestions to add the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwl.conf`:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=0 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1 
options iwlwifi d0i3_disable=1 
options iwlwifi uapsd_disable=1 
options iwlwifi lar_disable=1
```

In my case that didnt help. Actually I didnt have a iwl.conf, I created it. I did already have a iwlwifi.conf, and I tried adding those params there as well to no avail.

The content of that file were previously:

```
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac 80211
```

When I tried putting the param in that file I added them before the contents.

When I made changes to either of those configs I restarted of course.

Comment: Please remove *all* of the parameters you added and then show us: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the file iwl.conf that I created earlier with the params, and restored iwlwifi.conf to the original contents as shown above then restarted. `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` prints `lrwxrwxrwx root root 39 Feb 19 18:14 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

Comment: Your comment led me the solution thank you. Saw someone mention that I might have firewalled my DNS. I was indeed messing with the firewall however my intention was to disable it completely for a test (trying to fix an issue reaching my machine from external network). I downloaded the GUI "Firewall Configuration" from the Ubuntu Store and used the toggle to disabled the firewall (at least that's what I thought I was doing). Seems like this is what caused the issue.